# Login not working in flask application using flask_login

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-login

This is my app routes file:

```
from flask import (
    Flask, render_template, 
    request,redirect,url_for, flash
    )
from flask_smorest import Blueprint
from forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from models import User
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user
from db import db

blp = Blueprint("Routes", __name__, description = "Containes all app routes")

@blp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
@blp.route('/welcome')
@login_required
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome_user.html')
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
@blp.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash("You logged out")
    return redirect(url_for('Routes.index'))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
@blp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

        if user.check_password(form.password.data) and user is not None:
            #Log in the user

            login_user(user)
            flash('Logged in successfully.')

            next = request.args.get('next')

            if next == None or not next[0]=='/':
                next = url_for('Routes.welcome')

            return redirect(next)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form) 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
@blp.route('/register', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form  = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(email = form.email.data,
                    username = form.username.data,
                    password= form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Registered")
        return redirect(url_for('Routes.login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form = form)
```

This is my login html template

```
<form method="POST">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    {{form.email.label}}{{form.email()}}
    {{form.password.label}}{{form.password()}}
    {{form.submit()}}
</form>
```

This is the login form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SubmitField, PasswordField 
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo
from wtforms import ValidationError
from models import User

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(),Email()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('confirm_pass', message="Passwords don't match ")])
    confirm_pass = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Register")

    def check_email(self,field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email = field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError("Email already registered!")
        
    def check_username(self,field):
        if User.query.filter_by(username = field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError("Username already exists!")
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email:', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password: ', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Login")
```

And this is the Usermodel

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from db import db
from login import login_manager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt 
from flask_login import UserMixin

#Creating a model for user

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128)) 

    def __init__(self, email, username, password):
        bcrypt = Bcrypt()
        self.emails = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        bcrypt = Bcrypt()
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(password, self.password_hash)
```

**The problem is that when a user logs in the form is not redirecting to welcome.html as it should, and even when the next page is not welcome, the Login is simply not happening, I am being redirected to login.html each time I try to login.**

```
if next == None or not next[0]=='/':
                next = url_for('Routes.welcome')

            return redirect(next)
```

From what I have gathered over last several hours is that may be the check_password condition is not being satisfied somehow, to check this, I removed the condition altogether but the problem still persists.

Since it would be counter-productive to put all my code here I am leaving a google drive link to all the code.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y0UDUtnN8__l4xQu3fikpAbafrVm7xK4?usp=drive_link

This is all in pursuit of learning flask so I may have looked something over.

Thanks in advance, I have been on this for a while now.